Difficult inverse Fourier transform computation

I need the expression of the function $G(x)$ for which I have only the Fourier transform:
\begin{equation}
G(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ dp}{2 \pi}e^{i p x} \frac { \sinh\left( \frac{ \pi p(1-\alpha)}{2 \alpha} \right)}{2 \cosh\left( \frac{ \pi p}{2} \right)  \sinh\left( \frac{ \pi p}{2\alpha} \right)}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha >0 $ and real. For $\alpha=1$ $G(x)=0$  forall $x$ . I also know that $G(x)$ should vanish at infinity and should be real for real $x$.
I tried using InverseFourierTransform but it didn't give me any result. I tried to calculate it numerically with
Clear[p, x, \[Alpha]];
\[Alpha] = 1.5;
G(x) = Table[{x, 
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi] NIntegrate[
      Sinh[\[Pi] (p) (1 - \[Alpha])/(2 \[Alpha])]/(2 Cosh[\[Pi] p/
             2] * Sinh[\[Pi] (p)/(2 \[Alpha])]) E^(I p x), {p, -20, 
       20}]}, {x, -20, 20, .01}];
plot = ListLinePlot[{Re[inv], Im[inv]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "G(x)"}]

It gave me some result, but I now I don't know if it is the correct one.
how can I transform $G(x)$ in a continuous function of $x$ that can be used in other computations?
Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you.

In latex code you have: $e^{i p x}$ and in Mathematica code you have: $e^{-i p x}$
Decide with what sign, negative or positive?

Yes thank you, I edited the question with $e^{ipx}$.

If sign, is positive and from defintion in Mathematica is FourierTransform not InverseFourierTransform ?

Yes but in both cases I can't have analytical results. In my code I use Nintegrate. Of course I'd like to have an analytic formula but in other case I'd like to have also a numerical one.

Do you have any idea on the values of α?  Is it likely to be less than 1?  Numerically, it might be quite important.

I need to be bigger than 1, but actually I'd like to have an expression for general $\alpha$.

@rimbalzando9  I update my answer.

Numerically is easy to compute:
Clear[p, x, \[Alpha]];

\[Alpha] = 3/2;

f[x_?NumericQ] := 1/Sqrt[2 Pi] NIntegrate[(Csch[(p \[Pi])/(2 \[Alpha])] Sech[(p \[Pi])/
2] Sinh[(p \[Pi] (1 - \[Alpha]))/(2 \[Alpha])])* E^(I p x), {p, -200, 200}];

 data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -20, 20, 0.25}]; 
 
 ListLinePlot[{Re[data], Im[data]}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "G(x)"}, PlotRange -> All]

 (*a nice plot*)

Analytical solution  for: $\alpha =2$ (works for: alpha=4,6,...I didn't check further)
func = Csch[(p \[Pi])/(2 \[Alpha])] Sech[(p \[Pi])/2] Sinh[(
 p \[Pi] (1 - \[Alpha]))/(2 \[Alpha])] // TrigReduce //FullSimplify

(*1 - Coth[(p \[Pi])/(2 \[Alpha])] Tanh[(p \[Pi])/2]*)

FourierTransform[func /. \[Alpha] -> 2, p, x]

(*-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] Sech[x]*)

EDITED: 18.12.2024
For general alpha is very hard to find solution.Table for only a few  values:
Grid[{{"\[Alpha]", 1/3, 1/2, 3/2, 2, 3, 4, 6}, 
{"FourierTransform", (
Sqrt[2] x Csch[x])/\[Pi]^(3/2), 
1/\[Pi]^(3/2) Sqrt[2/
3] (I 3^(-((
    I x)/\[Pi])) ((1 - (-1)^(2/3))^((2 I x)/\[Pi])
       Beta[1/(1 + (-1)^(1/3)), -((I x)/\[Pi]), 
       1 + (I x)/\[Pi]] + (1 + (-1)^(1/3))^((
      2 I x)/\[Pi]) (Beta[1/(1 + (-1)^(1/3)), (I x)/\[Pi], 
         1 - (I x)/\[Pi]] - 
        Beta[1/6 (3 + I Sqrt[3]), -((I x)/\[Pi]), 
         1 + (I x)/\[Pi]])) - 2 E^(-x/3) \[Pi] Csch[x] + 
  E^(x/3) (-I Beta[1/6 (3 + I Sqrt[3]), (I x)/\[Pi], 
       1 - (I x)/\[Pi]] + 2 \[Pi] Csch[x])), (
Sqrt[2] (-((6 \[Pi]^2)/(\[Pi]^2 + 9 x^2)) - 
  I Sqrt[3]
    E^-x (Beta[1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[3]), 2 + (3 I x)/\[Pi], 0] - 
     Beta[1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]), 2 - (3 I x)/\[Pi], 0] + 
     E^(2 x) (Beta[1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[3]), 2 - (3 I x)/\[Pi], 0] - 
        Beta[1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]), 2 + (3 I x)/\[Pi], 0])) + 
  9 x Csch[3 x]))/(
3 \[Pi]^(3/2)), -Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] Sech[x], -((
4 Sqrt[6/\[Pi]] Cosh[x])/(1 + 2 Cosh[2 x])), -((
Sech[x] (2 + Sqrt[2] + 2 Sech[2 x]))/Sqrt[\[Pi]]), -((
Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] (5 + 2 (3 + Sqrt[3]) Cosh[2 x] + 
   2 (2 + Sqrt[3]) Cosh[4 x]) Sech[x])/(1 + 2 Cosh[4 x]))}}, 
Frame -> All]


UPDATE: 20.12.2024
We have:
$\mathcal{F}_p\left[\text{csch}\left(\frac{p \pi }{2 \alpha }\right) \text{sech}\left(\frac{p \pi }{2}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{p \pi  (1-\alpha )}{2 \alpha
   }\right)\right](x)=\\\mathcal{F}_p\left[1-\coth \left(\frac{p \pi }{2 \alpha }\right) \tanh \left(\frac{p \pi
   }{2}\right)\right](x)=\\\frac{\mathcal{M}_p\left[-\frac{2 \left(p^{\pi }-p^{\pi /\alpha }\right)}{\left(1+p^{\pi }\right) \left(-1+p^{\pi /\alpha
   }\right)}\right](i x)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=\\\frac{\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{\left(2 \left(p^{\pi }-p^{\pi /\alpha }\right)\right) p^{i x-1}}{\left(1+p^{\pi }\right)
   \left(-1+p^{\pi /\alpha }\right)} \, dp}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=\\\frac{\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{2 p^{-1+\pi +i x}}{\left(1+p^{\pi }\right) \left(-1+p^{\pi /\alpha
   }\right)} \, dp}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{\int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 p^{-1+i x+\frac{\pi }{\alpha }}}{\left(1+p^{\pi }\right) \left(-1+p^{\pi /\alpha }\right)} \,
   dp}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=\\\frac{\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\mathcal{M}_p\left[-\frac{2 p^{-1+\pi +i x}}{1+p^{\pi }}\right](s) \mathcal{M}_p\left[\frac{1}{-1+p^{\pi
   /\alpha }}\right](1-s)\right](1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\mathcal{M}_p\left[\frac{2 p^{-1+i x+\frac{\pi }{\alpha }}}{1+p^{\pi
   }}\right](s) \mathcal{M}_p\left[\frac{1}{-1+p^{\pi /\alpha }}\right](1-s)\right](1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=\\\frac{\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[(-1)^{-\frac{\alpha }{\pi
   }+\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \alpha  \csc (1-s-i x) \csc (\alpha -s \alpha )\right](1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi
   }}+\frac{\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[(-1)^{-\frac{\alpha }{\pi }+\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \alpha  \csc \left(1-s-i x-\frac{\pi }{\alpha
   }\right) \csc (\alpha -s \alpha )\right](1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=\\\frac{\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{(-1)^{-\frac{\alpha }{\pi }+\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }} \sqrt{2}
   \alpha  \Gamma \left(-\frac{s}{\pi }-\frac{i x}{\pi }\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{s}{\pi }+\frac{i x}{\pi }\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{\pi }-\frac{s
   \alpha }{\pi }\right) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{\alpha }{\pi }+\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }\right)}{\pi ^{5/2}}\right](1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi
   }}+\frac{\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{(-1)^{-\frac{\alpha }{\pi }+\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }} \sqrt{2} \alpha  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{\pi }-\frac{s}{\pi }-\frac{i
   x}{\pi }\right) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{\pi }+\frac{s}{\pi }+\frac{i x}{\pi }\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{\pi }-\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }\right) \Gamma
   \left(1-\frac{\alpha }{\pi }+\frac{s \alpha }{\pi }\right)}{\pi ^{5/2}}\right](1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=\text{FoxH function}$
using:
$\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](s)=\mathcal{M}_x[f(-\log (x))](i s)$ and $\int_0^{\infty } \text{f1}(x) \text{f2}(x) \, dx=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}[\mathcal{M}_x[\text{f1}(x)](s) \mathcal{M}_x[\text{f2}(x)](1-s)](1)$.
Where: $\mathcal{F}_x$ is FourierTransform,$\mathcal{M}_s$ and $\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}$ is MellinTransform and InverseMellinTransform
General solution expressed by FoxH function is valid ONLY for: $ 0<\alpha <\pi$
Re[(Sqrt[2] \[Alpha] FoxH[{{{1 + (I x)/\[Pi], 
   1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, {{{0, -(\[Alpha]/\[Pi])}, {1, \[Alpha]/\[Pi]}, \
{1 + (I x)/\[Pi], 1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, (-1)^(-(\[Alpha]/\[Pi]))])/\[Pi]^(
5/2) + (Sqrt[2] \[Alpha] FoxH[{{{1 + (I x)/\[Pi] + 1/\[Alpha], 
   1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, {{{0, -(\[Alpha]/\[Pi])}, {1, \[Alpha]/\[Pi]}, \
{1 + (I x)/\[Pi] + 1/\[Alpha], 
   1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, (-1)^(-(\[Alpha]/\[Pi]))])/\[Pi]^(5/2)]

For example: $\alpha=2$ and $x=1$ Mathematica can't simplify to simpler form analytical(or elementary) expression using FunctionExpand and can't get numeric value using N command.
Workaround only to get numerics values:
$Version
(*"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)


{N[Re[(Sqrt[
     2] \[Alpha] FoxH[{{{1 + (I x)/\[Pi], 
         1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, {{{0, -(\[Alpha]/\[Pi])}, {1, \[Alpha]/\[Pi]}, {1 + (I x)/\[Pi], 
         1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, (-1)^(-(\[Alpha]/\[Pi]))])/\[Pi]^(
    5/2) + (Sqrt[
     2]\[Alpha] FoxH[{{{1 + (I x)/\[Pi] + 1/\[Alpha], 
         1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, {{{0, -(\[Alpha]/\[Pi])}, {1, \[Alpha]/\[Pi]}, {1 + (I x)/\[Pi] + 1/\[Alpha], 
         1/\[Pi]}}, {}}, (-1)^(-(\[Alpha]/\[Pi]))])/\[Pi]^(
    5/2)] /. Pi -> 314159265358979/100000000000000 /. \[Alpha] -> 
  2 /. x -> 1 // FunctionExpand, 14], 
N[-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] Sech[x] /. x -> 1, 14]}

{-0.51707249951873, -0.51707249951873}(*OK*)

UPDATE: 21.12.2024
If we change variable:
$$\mathcal{F}_p\left[\text{csch}\left(\frac{p \pi }{2 \alpha }\right) \text{sech}\left(\frac{p \pi }{2}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{p \pi  (1-\alpha )}{2 \alpha
   }\right)\right](x)=\mathcal{F}_p\left[1-\coth \left(\frac{p \pi }{2 \alpha }\right) \tanh \left(\frac{p \pi }{2}\right)\right](x)=2 \alpha  \left(\mathcal{F}_t[1-\coth (\pi  t) \tanh (\pi  t \alpha
   )](2 x \alpha )\right)$$
following what I wrote above, we get General solution expressed by FoxH function  valid for: $ 0<\alpha \leq 8$:
  {N[Re[E^(I/2 + x \[Alpha])/(
     Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(
      5/2))*(FoxH[{{{1 - 1/(2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), 1/(
           2 \[Pi] \[Alpha])}, {1/(
           2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), -(1/(
            2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]))}}, {}}, {{{1/(2 \[Pi]) - (
            I x \[Alpha])/\[Pi], -(1/(2 \[Pi]))}, {1 - 1/(
            2 \[Pi]) + (I x \[Alpha])/\[Pi], 1/(2 \[Pi])}}, {}}, 
        E^(I/2)] /. 
       Pi -> 31415926535897932384626433832795/
        10000000000000000000000000000000) - 
    E^(I/2 - I \[Pi] \[Alpha] + x \[Alpha])/(
     Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(
      5/2))*(FoxH[{{{1 - 1/(2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), 1/(
           2 \[Pi] \[Alpha])}, {1/(
           2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]), -(1/(
            2 \[Pi] \[Alpha]))}}, {}}, {{{1/(
            2 \[Pi]) - \[Alpha] - (I x \[Alpha])/\[Pi], -(1/(
            2 \[Pi]))}, {1 - 1/(2 \[Pi]) + (
            I x \[Alpha])/\[Pi] + \[Alpha], 1/(2 \[Pi])}}, {}}, 
        E^(I/2)] /. 
       Pi -> 31415926535897932384626433832795/
        10000000000000000000000000000000)] /. \[Alpha] -> 8 /. 
 x -> 1 // FunctionExpand, 30] - 
 1/Sqrt[2 Pi]
 NIntegrate[ 
 E^(I p x)
    Csch[(p \[Pi])/(2 \[Alpha])] Sech[(p \[Pi])/2] Sinh[(
    p \[Pi] (1 - \[Alpha]))/(2 \[Alpha])] /. \[Alpha] -> 8 /. 
 x -> 1, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 42]}

 (*{-3.6262392*10^-22 + 0.*10^-42 I}*)

EDITED:
for: $\alpha>0$
$\mathcal{F}_p\left[\text{csch}\left(\frac{p \pi }{2 \alpha }\right) \text{sech}\left(\frac{p \pi }{2}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{p \pi  (1-\alpha )}{2 \alpha }\right)\right](x)=\\\Re\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{2} \left(\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\frac{i x}{\pi }+\frac{-1+k}{\alpha }\right)\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{i x}{\pi }+\frac{k}{\alpha }\right)\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{i x}{\pi
   }+\frac{k}{\alpha }\right)\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{i x}{\pi }+\frac{-1+k+\alpha }{\alpha }\right)\right)\right)}{\pi ^{3/2}}\right)$
Check for $\alpha=2$ and $x=1$
{Re[NSum[(Sqrt[2] (PolyGamma[0, 
     1/2 (2 + (I x)/\[Pi] + (-1 + k)/\[Alpha])] + 
    PolyGamma[0, 1/2 (-((I x)/\[Pi]) + k/\[Alpha])] - 
    PolyGamma[0, 1/2 (1 - (I x)/\[Pi] + k/\[Alpha])] - 
    PolyGamma[0, 
     1/2 ((I x)/\[Pi] + (-1 + k + \[Alpha])/\[Alpha])]))/\[Pi]^(
 3/2) /. \[Alpha] -> 2 /. x -> 1, {k, 1, Infinity}]], 
1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
MellinTransform[-((
 2 (p^\[Pi] - p^(\[Pi]/\[Alpha])))/((1 + p^\[Pi]) (-1 + 
    p^(\[Pi]/\[Alpha])))) /. \[Alpha] -> 2, p, I*1.0, 
Method -> "Numeric"]}

(*{-0.517072, -0.517072 + 0. I}*)

UPDATE: 22.12.2024
For: $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha \geq 0$
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \left(1-\coth \left(\frac{p \pi }{2 \alpha }\right) \tanh \left(\frac{p \pi }{2}\right)\right) \exp (i p x) \, dp=\color{blue}{\sum _{k=0}^{\alpha -1} \left(\frac{(-1)^{\frac{1}{\alpha }+\frac{2 k}{\alpha }} \left(-(-1)^{\frac{1}{\alpha }+\frac{2 k}{\alpha }}\right)^{-\frac{(\pi +i x) \alpha }{\pi }} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \csc ((\pi +i x)
   \alpha )}{-1+(-1)^{\frac{1}{\alpha }+\frac{2 k}{\alpha }}}+\frac{i \left(-(-1)^{\frac{1}{\alpha }+\frac{2 k}{\alpha }}\right)^{-\frac{i x \alpha }{\pi }} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \text{csch}(x \alpha
   )}{-1+(-1)^{\frac{1}{\alpha }+\frac{2 k}{\alpha }}}\right)}$
  G1[\[Alpha]_, x_] :=Sum[((-1)^(1/\[Alpha] + (
  2 k)/\[Alpha]) (-(-1)^(1/\[Alpha] + (2 k)/\[Alpha]))^(-(((\[Pi] + I x) \[Alpha])/\[Pi]))
  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Csc[(\[Pi] + I x) \[Alpha]])/(-1 + (-1)^(
  1/\[Alpha] + (2 k)/\[Alpha])) + (
  I (-(-1)^(1/\[Alpha] + (2 k)/\[Alpha]))^(-((I x \[Alpha])/\[Pi]))
  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Csch[x \[Alpha]])/(-1 + (-1)^(
  1/\[Alpha] + (2 k)/\[Alpha])), {k, 0, \[Alpha] - 1}]
  
  Grid[{{"\[Alpha]", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 
  Join[{"FourierTransform"}, 
  Table[G1[\[Alpha], x], {\[Alpha], 1, 7}]] // FullSimplify}, 
  Frame -> All]



Thank you very much!
